# How to simulate a POST to a URL using Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, csrf, httpresponse

I'd like to create a view function that simulates the user getting a form at `url`, setting one of the form's input variables (`my_flag`) and submitting that form. I've tried two different approaches and both have failed.

**Approach 1: use python requests to get and post to `url`**

```
def simulate_post(request):
    url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('my_app:form_view', args=[666]))
    response = requests.get(url)
    csrftoken = response.cookies['csrftoken']
    print("TOKEN =", csrftoken)
    response = requests.post(url, data={'my_flag': True, 'csrftoken': csrftoken}, headers={'Referer': url})
    return response
```

This approach fails as follows. Obviously I'm not even passing on the CSRF token successfully:

```
TOKEN = EXFI2xoKxHounDIRnqdrPwLpdXGe3zuZATErKINTuxJsgzV7Oj6lPP6kzsjQVc7z
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /form_view/666/
[12/Feb/2021 16:44:02] "POST /form_view/666/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2868
Internal Server Error: /simulate_post/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/myapp-MCS7ouoX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/myapp-MCS7ouoX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/myapp-MCS7ouoX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**Approach 2: use RequestFactory**

```
def simulate_post(request):
    url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('my_app:form_view', args=[666]))
    factory = RequestFactory()
    factory.user = request.user
    response = factory.get(url)
    response = factory.post(url, data={'my_flag': True})
    return response
```

This approach fails as follows:

```
Internal Server Error: /simulate_post/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/myapp-MCS7ouoX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/myapp-MCS7ouoX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/myapp-MCS7ouoX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

It appears that I'm not returning a proper response in either case from my simulated POST. How do I get this to work?

**Update: Approach 3 [incomplete]**

Pursuing the suggestion of @schillingt and Iain to refactor out the guts of the search/form view I'm trying to leverage, here's a third potential approach, if I knew how to proceeded.

Making the first HTTP request, the GET, basically is equivalent to something like this:

```
context = search_context(request, data)
return render(request, 'myapp/display.html', context)
```

That `context` includes a `form` variable which is the form for the search. If I could set the form as I wanted and turn `request` into a POST it would produce what I needed. Not sure how though...

Comment: Is this for a test?

Comment: No, this would be for the site itself. The form is basically for filtering searches, and I want a view function that runs the search with the form filled out in a particular way.

Comment: Can you share the code for the search/form view? Moving the code that takes the form data and generates a response to a shared function that you can pass a hard-coded value to would probably make sense

Comment: If this is within the same app, I would avoid issuing the request to the other URL and instead refactor that logic out into a common function and use it directly here. It seems unnecessary to involve another HTTP request in this view.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, @schillingt and Iain. If this were a straightforward search/form view, I'd definitely take that route. The trouble is the search view is part of a general system that allows custom classes and templates to be loaded, and currently those classes do not have an interface to allow custom variables to be passed in. I could add it, and probably should at some point, but was hoping for an easy and direct solution to this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) to get the actual view function that will be called for the given url. Passing a POST request generated from a `RequestFactory` to the view returned by `resolve` should work

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.test import RequestFactory
from django.urls import resolve


def simulate_post(request):
    url = reverse('my_app:form_view', args=[666])
    factory = RequestFactory()
    post_request = factory.post(url, data={'my_flag': True})
    resolved = resolve(url)
    return resolved.func(post_request, *resolved.args, **resolved.kwargs)
```

Comment: This is getting really close! I had to add `post_request.user = request.user` after the `post_request =` line so the search view would work, but it does now successfully perform the search and show the form correctly set. The only thing missing seems to be the CSRF token. When I do another search on the form this yields, it fails with the error: `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)`

Answer (score 0):

The name of the input is `csrfmiddlewaretoken`.

```
def simulate_post(request):
    url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('my_app:form_view', args=[666]))
    response = requests.get(url)
    csrftoken = response.cookies['csrftoken']
    print("TOKEN =", csrftoken)
    response = requests.post(url, data={'my_flag': True, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken}, headers={'Referer': url})
    return response
```

Comment: Sorry, I'd tried that too and the results for **Approach 1** are exactly the same.